# how can I make my app not break on certain screen sizes due to scaling

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm building an app and I can't figure out how can I make my app not break on certain screen sizes.
I want the app to have a standard look on all devices.

[how it should look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSLPv.png)

[how it looks on the pixel 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gUs5.png)

[how it looks on a tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6CMZ.png)

```
<ImageView
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/hub_background" />




<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="19dp" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="19dp" />



<ImageView
    android:translationZ="3dp"
    android:id="@+id/background2"
    android:layout_width="409dp"
    android:layout_height="1200dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:maxWidth="302dp"
    android:maxHeight="722dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/start_anim_background_color"
    tools:visibility="gone" />


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/monthProgress"
    android:layout_width="327dp"
    android:layout_height="159dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.494"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:ignore="=">

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/topPanel"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_shape_capsule_empty"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/time"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/money"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/money"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="1500$"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="150hrs"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="RtlCompat" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Your month's progress:"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#757575"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/topPanel"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/topPanel"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/topPanel" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <android.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_shape_lightedge4"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="start a new\nshift"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:translationZ="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="47dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="360dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <android.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_shape_lightedge2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="see all of\nyour shifts"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:translationZ="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout3"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="47dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="47dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

    <android.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_shape_lightedge3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="settings"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:translationZ="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout4"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

    <android.widget.Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_shape_lightedge1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="about"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:translationZ="3dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

I'm using up as my measurement unit for everything.

Comment: Without seeing your layout code no one can help you. Secondly part of designing for Android is making sure your views can bad adaptive. A 4inch phone and a 10inch tablet are not going to look the same. Plus many devices have different aspect ratios.

Comment: I think you better start off with reading some documentation regarding designing apps for multiple screen sizes: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.
In particular, using ConstraintLayout(s)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible for it to look the same on all different screens as they have different ratios. But what is possible is to make it look very similar on different screens with the same ratio.

Generally the best is going with `dp` since the user can then rescale your app via Android settings if he/she has sight difficulties (to e.g. make it bigger). But if you prefer your app to always use the same design ratios you can for example use `GridLayout`s and weights. You can then specify how much percentage of your screen should be covered by a view. Additionally, you could of course also always go by manually implementing stuff like

```
desiredRatio = 0.4f;
viewHeight = desiredRatio * getMeasuredHeight();
```

and then applying the height to your view by changing the LayoutParams or implementing your own ViewGroup and do the whole onLayout stuff yourself (sure possible and necessary in rare occasions)

Generally, I'd try to get it done with GridLayouts or LinearLayouts using weights and in rare cases implement your own ViewGroup.

So in your case that could be something like

```
<androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height=match_parent"
app:orientation="horizontal"
app:columnCount="2">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/monthProgress"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
app:layout_columnWeight="1"
//...The rest of your stuff here
/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/layout_1"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
app:layout_columnWeight="1"
//...The rest of your stuff here
/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/layout_3"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
app:layout_columnWeight="1"
//...The rest of your stuff here
/>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:id="@+id/layout_4"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
app:layout_rowWeight="1"
app:layout_columnWeight="1"
//...The rest of your stuff here
/>

</androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
```

Sorry for the missing indentations, the StackOverFlow code "editor" is just horrible.

Anyhow, that's how you'll get some parts done. Make sure to set the height in your ConstraintLayouts to "0dp", likewise with the width. Otherwise, GridLayout won't be able to do what you want.

Additionally, you used `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in your ImageView. That will look weird. Instead, I'd recommend `centerCrop` instead.